# C++ - Casting const by using the address explanation

Tags: c++, casting, constants

I worte the following code in c++ .
I want to do casting to a const variable and change it,
this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int const a = 5;
    int* ptr = (int*)&a;
    *ptr = 10;
    cout<<"a is : "<< a << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

This code passed the compiler, I expect the program to print an the screen 10 ,
but the result in the screen is 5.
When I run the debugger the memory in &a has been changed to 10 like I expected.
Any idea why?

Comment: it seems you have run into a pretty smart compiler

Comment: You should have gotten some warnings about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all this is undefined behavior. Don't do it. Second, the compiler optimized away actually looking at the memory at `&a` when you print out `a` because you told the compiler `a` would never change (you said it was `const`). So it actually turned into...

`cout << "a is : "<<5 << endl;`

Comment: Then define is the same as const?

Comment: @bennyperl sometimes it effectively is. It's much harder for the compiler to perform this kind of optimization when you aren't dealing with intrinsic types (`int`, `float`, etc) though.

Answer (score 3):

You are invoking undefined behavior with the code in question, trying to change a variable declared as `const` by casting away the constness is not allowed (unless the *const variable* is really a reference to a variable which isn't `const`).

One plausible, and highly likely, explanation to your result is that the compiler knows that the value of `a` shouldn't change, therefor it can pretty much replace all occurences of `a` with `5`. ie. the "*look up*" is optimized out.

*Why look at the adress of `a` to read it's value when it's declared as always being `5`?*

---

**Let's take a look at what instructions a compiler might turn the snippet into**

*foo.cpp*

```
void func (int)
{
  /* ... */
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const int a = 10; 

  int * p     = &const_cast<int&> (a);

  *p = 20; 

  func (a);
}
```

assembly instructions of `main` as given by `g++ -S foo.cpp`

```
main:
.LFB1:
  .cfi_startproc
  pushq %rbp
  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
  .cfi_offset 6, -16 
  movq  %rsp, %rbp
  .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
  subq  $32, %rsp
  movl  %edi, -20(%rbp)
  movq  %rsi, -32(%rbp)
  movl  $10, -12(%rbp)
  leaq  -12(%rbp), %rax
  movq  %rax, -8(%rbp)
  movq  -8(%rbp), %rax # store the adress of `a` in %rax
  movl  $20, (%rax)    # store 20 at the location pointed to by %rax  (ie. &a)
  movl  $10, %edi      # put 10 in register %edi (placeholder for first argument to function)
                       # # notice how the value is not read from `a`
                       # # but is a constant
  call  _Z4funci       # call `func`
  movl  $0, %eax
  leave
  .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
  ret 
  .cfi_endproc
```

As seen above the value of `20` is indeed put at the address stored in `%rax` where `(%rax)` contains the address of `a` (`movl $20, (%rax)`), but the argument to our call to `void func (int)` is the constant number `10` (`movl $10, %edi`).

As said earlier; the compiler assumes that the value of `a` doesn't change, and instead of reading the memory location every time `a` is used it will instead replace it with the constant value `10`.